# Loading a csv of empty string and null into redshift causes nulls to be converted to empty strings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a csv that has rows that have a mix of null (two delimiters in a row) and "". How do I load this into redshift as is. I want "" to be loaded into redshift as "" and I want null values to be loaded into redshift as null.

```
283858817256731,"",2023-01-01 04:25:47.686607,2023-01-01 04:25:47.686038,,,,
151e1e6d75455b17b43e2,"",2023-01-01 04:26:59.284768,2023-01-01 04:26:59.284354,,,,
3005867602921,"",2023-01-01 04:32:37.476288,2023-01-01 04:32:42.347546,,,"",
300450878333,"",2022-12-30 07:56:45.10391,2023-01-28 06:34:11.616317,,,"",
3005869211328,"",2023-01-01 04:35:35.413979,2023-01-01 04:35:50.054747,,,"",
2830888423936,,2023-01-01 04:36:50.889579,2023-01-01 04:36:50.889177,,"",,
```

this copy command seems to create a table in redshift where there are no null values. Why is this?

```
COPY jwan.users_birth_dates_s3_copy
FROM 's3://...<some path>'
iam_role  <some role>;
CSV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSV file format double quotes are used to help clarity but are not part of the data.  So ,, and ,””, are the same.

If you want to input a NULL into Redshift from CSV you need to set a string to be the NULL indicator and set this string in the NULL AS option to COPY.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-null-as

To stay with CSV you will need to change your data input file so that the lines you want to have as NULL are indicated by some NULL AS string.  OR (I think this wil work) you can change the file format away from CSV but change the delimiter to comma (,).  You can then set NULL AS to ‘“”’ so that back-to-back double quotes will be interpreted at NULL.  Doing this could have some adverse side effects though - you will lose the CSV interpretation engine and every case of “” will become NULL.  Your sample data doesn’t have anything that will break if you left CSV format but only trying will tell.